# How to return a list in a function without " "

Tags: python, list, python-2.x

I have a list `a = ['type1','type2','type3']` and I have a function. In the function I want to return the list, but without the `' '`. Is this possible? When I return I get with the `" "`.

Comment: You mean return it as a string? Something like `[type1,type2,type3]`?

Comment: Yes. Like a string, without ' ' or " "

Comment: If you mean "like" a string, see @Martin's answer. If you mean as a string, something like `"[%s]" % ','.join(a)` will do it.

Comment: Suppose you could do this. How would you distinguish between `['a,b', 'c']`, and `['a', 'b,c']`? without the quote marks, they'd both look like `[a,b,c]`.

Comment: @user3297266 why don't you give us what you're getting right now, and what you WANT to get. I don't think we're understanding you clearly. It sounds to me like you want a list `[type1,type2,type3]`, but if those aren't actually local variables this will fail (and DEFINITELY isn't the best way to do what you're trying to do anyway)

Comment: You are also modifying a global list; run the function more than once and you end up accumulating results with every call.

Answer (score 4):

Python shows you values in containers such as a list as *value representations*; for strings that means you are shown the literal string value, with the quotes.

That does **not** mean the string values contain actual quotes.

You can of course print something to the terminal that shows just the string values, joined by commas and surrounded by square brackets:

```
print '[{0}]'.format(', '.join(yourlist))
```

but that won't alter the list object, nor should you want to.

As for your code, what is wrong here is that you are modifying a *global* list, in the module. When you import the module the `make_table(tresort_liste, sla_liste, wb)` line runs which alters `table_liste` and `lbmer`:

```
>>> import yourmodule
[['b\xc3\xb8k', 155.73786516665265], ['eik', 200.23439807141054], ['rogn', 149.1107219680717], ['poppel', 152.3522594021602], ['furu', 876.0254915624212], ['gran', 350.4101966249685], ['douglasgran', 778.6893258332633]]
>>> yourmodule.table_liste
[['b\xc3\xb8k', 155.73786516665265], ['eik', 200.23439807141054], ['rogn', 149.1107219680717], ['poppel', 152.3522594021602], ['furu', 876.0254915624212], ['gran', 350.4101966249685], ['douglasgran', 778.6893258332633]]
>>> yourmodule.lbmer
[155.73786516665265, 200.23439807141054, 149.1107219680717, 152.3522594021602, 876.0254915624212, 350.4101966249685, 778.6893258332633]
```

Your test then runs the `make_table` function *again* and your test arguments are appended to these global lists. As a result, the method returns more data than you are expecting and your test fails:

```
>>> names = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> sla = [1, 2, 4]
>>> lbm = [15.3, 7.65, 3.825]
>>> zip(*yourmodule.make_table(names, sla, 50000))
[('b\xc3\xb8k', 'eik', 'rogn', 'poppel', 'furu', 'gran', 'douglasgran', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi'), (155.73786516665265, 200.23439807141054, 149.1107219680717, 152.3522594021602, 876.0254915624212, 350.4101966249685, 778.6893258332633, 155.73786516665265, 200.23439807141054, 149.1107219680717)]
```

Moral of the story: Don't use globals.

Your code could be simplified to:

```
import math

def compute_lbm(sla, wb):
    return (0.3 + math.sqrt(0.0045 * wb)) / sla

def make_table(tresorter, slaer, wb):
    return [[sort, compute_lbm(sla, wb)] for sort, sla in zip(tresorter, slaer)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sla_liste = [0.045, 0.035, 0.047, 0.046, 0.008, 0.020, 0.009]
    tresort_liste = ["bøk", "eik", "rogn", "poppel", "furu", "gran", "douglasgran"]
    wb = 10000

    print make_table(tresort_liste, sla_liste, wb)
```

which incidentally won't use globals. The `print make_table()` call at the end will not be executed when used as a module either, only if you run this file directly as the main script.

You're use of `assertAlmostEqual()` is missing the `places` or `delta` argument, you need to specify how close the output needs to match.

The quotes you were chasing are definitely not an issue here.

Comment: @Aaron: the `0` is only needed in Python 2.6 and earlier; for Python 2.7 and 3.x positional slots are auto-numbered.

Comment: Do you know that huge corporations who have committed to Python are still stuck in earlier versions? I'm using 2.6 all day long. The {0} is forward compatible, but the {} is not backwards compatible.

Comment: @AaronHall: Sure, but that could have been a comment instead of an edit. :-)

Comment: Just trying to make things as easy as possible for everybody. :)